# How to take a photo, save it and pass the photo uri for Android custom camera properly?

Tags: java, android

So I am trying to take a picture in CameraActivity and pass the Uri back to MainActivity.

In CameraActivity.java

```
@Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log("Picture Taken 1");
        if (data != null) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_CAMERA_DATA, data);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
      } else {
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
      }
      finish();

    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
private void addButtonListeners() {

        mBtnCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_camera);


        mBtnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
                //getCameraInstance();

                mFileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

                i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFileUri);

                startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
                //startActivity(i);

            }
        });
}
/**
     * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image
        log("data is passed 1");
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                // successfully captured the image


                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                byte[] cameraData = extras.getByteArray(CameraActivity.EXTRA_CAMERA_DATA);
                if (cameraData != null) {
                  Bitmap mCameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(cameraData, 0, cameraData.length);

                  mImgTaken.setImageBitmap(mCameraBitmap);

                }

                //addPhotoToGallery();
                //previewCapturedPhoto();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture

            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Failed to capture photo, Please take again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

The photo I got from this is just a thumbnail and I want a full size image. However, I think the proper way might be saving a temporary file and then pass the uri with your intent.  Can anyone point me a direction on how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I get a full size image like this:

```
imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () + "/someFolder/" + someName + ".jpg");


String fileName = imgFile.getAbsolutePath();

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)));

startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA);
```

Then, in your onActivityResult, you can treat the URI any way you wish

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String filePath;
    Bitmap _bitmapPreScale = null;


    if (requestCode == REQUEST_FROM_FILE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri targetUri = data.getData();
            ... (do something)
```

Comment: Yeah, but you're using a third party camera app, right?

Comment: no, that's an intent to fire up an activity that can take a picture. This brings up the standard camera app

Comment: Yah, that's what I meant. The way you do it can use the standard android or third party camera.  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraActivity.class); I use my own camera class for the camera and was wondering how the Uri and file are passed back to the MainActivity. It will be similar to how the standard camera pass the uri and photos back to your code. :)